# How do I make spread effect to bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, convolution

In my app I have text which I'm converting to bitmap and then I need it turn into a cloud smoothly and then dissapear. I'm using Convolution Matrix to blur bitmap and make it dissapear.

I don't know how to blur-spread a bitmap though. By blur-spread I mean making a picture in bitmap larger and smoother. Its like airplane trace. First it has sharp edges, then it spreads and then it dissapears.
Any thoughts about spreading picture?

Preliminary code for blur-dissarear (not ideal, needs improvement)

```
           new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (k < 150) {
                        k++;
                        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText(k + "");

                        bitmapEffect = createBitmap_convolve(bitmapEffect, matrix_blur, 0.98f);

                        image1.setImageBitmap(bitmapEffect);
                        new Handler().postDelayed(this, 16);
                    }
                }
            });

private Bitmap createBitmap_convolve(Bitmap src, float[] coefficients, float factor) {

    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(src.getWidth(),
            src.getHeight(), src.getConfig());

    RenderScript renderScript = RenderScript.create(activity);

    Allocation input = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, src);
    Allocation output = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, result);

    ScriptIntrinsicConvolve3x3 convolution = ScriptIntrinsicConvolve3x3
            .create(renderScript, Element.U8_4(renderScript));
    convolution.setInput(input);

    normalize(coefficients, factor);

    convolution.setCoefficients(coefficients);
    convolution.forEach(output);

    output.copyTo(result);
    renderScript.destroy();
    return result;
}

private void normalize(float[] coefficients, float normalizeFactor) {
        float sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < coefficients.length; i++) {
            sum += coefficients[i];
        }
        if(sum == 0){
            sum = 1;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < coefficients.length; i++) {
            coefficients[i] = coefficients[i] / sum * normalizeFactor;
        }
    }

float[] matrix_blur =
        { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
          1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
          1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
```

Comment: Hello which API are you using for renders criteria. ..is shader programming hard to learn or easy because you can copy paste everything for your needs?

Answer (score 0):

You want to resize/strech your bitmap?!

The Bitmap class has a method for that Bitmap.createScaledBitmap (bitmap,new width, new height, true);

Comment: I dont want to resize. I have white object in bitmap. I want that white color to spread around that object.